Highlighting actual columns in vim
I'd like to highlight two columns when editing files in vim (columns 73 and 133, for editing fixed and free form Fortran code, if you're curious). I can easily do it with set colorcolumn=73,133, but it has at least a couple of issues that bother me:

The highlight messes up with copy-pasting with mouse selection in Konsole (and maybe other terminals). Specifically, without the highlight I can select multiple lines with the mouse, and when I paste them, they're pasted without trailing blanks (that in itself can be an issue, but it's generally what I want). With the highlights, however, whenever I select full lines, they're pasted with lots of trailing blanks, enough to cover the highlighted columns (i.e., up to line 133). I'd like the highlights to be only visual and not affect the copy-pasting.

When a line is soft-wrapped (with linebreak and breakat=\ , so only allowed at spaces, and the first part of the line might not extend the full window width), the highlighted columns are still the "virtual" columns, computed as if the line was broken at full window length, and not at the places where the actual nth characters shows or would show.
So this is an unwrapped line:

Note the highlights (pink) at columns 73 and 133, and the cursor (dark red) at column 133.
Now with a narrower window the line wraps:

and the second highlighted column is at line 123 instead, because the line was wrapped "early". The cursor is still at column 133.


Is there any way to solve any of these annoyances?
